# Check if Joomla installed in subdirectory

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I need to find out if Joomla has subdirectory or it's on the main domain area, i.e domain.com or domain.com/livesite

Is there a way to find this out ?

Comment: Two possible ways is check one with the htaccess file and second one is check the joomla echo baseUrl().

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.